# Sticky Bar Can't do the float:right

Tags: html, css

I've used my bootstrap-3 website for the sticky bar, I try to do like this [How TO - Sticky Social Bar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_social_bar.asp) and I do some modification,

I used the `float: right;` but it does not work,

my conflict is , `that bar cant set to the web site float:right` ,I want to take the right side

anyone know how to do that.

Thanks.

```css
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;  float: right;

}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;height:2000px;}

.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
<body>


<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="facebook">RFQ</a>

</div>


<div class="content">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use  `right:0;` when you give its position - `fixed` or `absolute`.

Also - a codepen example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aRqvqG  (the example you mentioned in your question)

```css
.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;height:2000px;}

.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
   right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
<body>


<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="facebook">RFQ</a>

</div>


<div class="content">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you can also use position:relative as it will occupy its space in the page and can be moved to right or left and bottom or top. when we give position as absolute or fixed it won't occupy any specific space for it and it depends on its parent element which has the position as relative

Answer (score 2):

Use `right:0;` instead of `float:right` because `float:right` will not work with `position:fixed;`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `right:0;`

```
.icon-bar {
right:0;
}
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;height:2000px;}

.icon-bar {
right:0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
<body>


<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="facebook">RFQ</a>

</div>


<div class="content">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just omit position: fixed from your icon-bar class and then change it to float:right;

```css
position: fixed;
  top: 50%;  float: right;

}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;height:2000px;}

.icon-bar {
  /*position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
   right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);*/
  float: right;
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
<body>


<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="facebook">RFQ</a>

</div>


<div class="content">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Or if you want it to stick on the right do it like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;height:2000px;}

.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
   right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
<body>


<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="facebook">RFQ</a>

</div>


<div class="content">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        top: 300px;
        right: 0;
        border: 1px solid #363636;
        width: 40px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #F1F1F1;
        float: right;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.